# System Overview in Salesforce

Tags: limits

In Salesforce under system overview section, for "Business Logic" does it include approval process as well or just workflow rules.

In our org it shows "96% (960 of 1000) ", we just want to know if this limit includes only workflow rules or both workflow rules & approval process.

Also could you please clarify if we have an INACTIVE workflow rules does it still count in the numbers here?

Answer (score 8):

System Overview:

- Does not include approval processes
- All active and inactive workflow rules are count against limit.

If you click on count number just below "RULES" sub-section in "Business Logic" section you can see workflow rules.